# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance of StudentSubject

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have three entities in hierarchy 1)Teacher 2)Student 3)Subject
In Teacher Entity there OneToMany relationship to Student class. Student class has OneToMany relationship with Subject class.
I have specific situation in which Teacher has 5 students and students have many subjects assigned to them. I am fetching entity of Teacher and fetching list of Student from teacher entity. Out of 5, I am removing one Student entity from list using **remove()** function. While saving Teacher entity, getting error as
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance of StudentSubject ** Here StudentSubject is child entity of Student.

```
public class Teacher {

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="studentCode", orphanRemoval = true)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch(org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode.SELECT)
@org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize(size=30)
private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

}

public class Student {

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="studentSubjectCode", orphanRemoval = true)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch(org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode.SELECT)
@org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize(size=30)
private List<StudentSubject> studentsubjects = new ArrayList<StudentSubject>();

}


public class StudentSubject {


}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after debugging and exploring more, I found out solution for this issue.
Before removing student entity from list of parent, i refreshed that entity. All references of StudentSubject array then became active and in turn solved the issue of detached entity while saving Teacher object.